# FOP2 Wallboard Plugin

Tags: php, mysql, plugins, asterisk

I am using FOP2 Full Wallboard plugin which adds three different widgets for queue wallboard displays: Agent list, Waiting calls list, Queue Info/Stats boxes. The wallboard can display statistical information taken from Asternic CCStats PRO. Widgets are completely customizable using html, css and javascript by using dustjs templates. Here is the full wallboard [documentation](https://www.fop2.com/docs/wallboard_guide.php).

In the back-end it loads a script called **getstatsfromasternic.php**

I intend to display total outgoing in my Queue Template but the problem is that it only accepts Wallboard Queue Variables as declared in the documentation.

**getstatsfromasternic** script code:

```
<?php
if (php_sapi_name() !='cli') exit;
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../dblib.php");
require_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/../../asmanager.php");

$ini_array       = parse_ini_file('fullwallboard.ini', true);
$asternic_dir    = $ini_array['asternic_install_directory'];
if($asternic_dir == '') {
    $asternic_dir = '/var/www/html/stats';
}

require_once("$asternic_dir/config.php");
$SLA_ANSWERED = Array();

$DEBUG            = 0;
$SLA_ANSWERED[''] = 20;

$loggedInAgents = array();
$condagent ='';
if(isset($argv[1])) {
    $agente=base64_decode($argv[1]);
    $condagent = " AND agent IN ($agente) ";
    $partes = preg_split("/,/",$agente);
    foreach($partes as $valor) {
        $loggedInAgents[]=substr($valor,1,-1);
    }
}

if($DEBUG & 1) {
    $fp = fopen("/tmp/wallboard_debug.log","a");
    fputs($fp,"GET WALLBOARD STATS ($condagent)\n\n");
    if(count($loggedInAgents)>0) {
        fputs($fp,"Agents logged:\n");
        fputs($fp,print_r($loggedInAgents,1)."\n");
    }
}

$astman = new AsteriskManager();

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"MySQL host: $DBHOST, user: $DBUSER, pass: $DBPASS, database name: $DBNAME\n");
}

// Connect to MySQL
$db = new dbcon($DBHOST, $DBUSER, $DBPASS, $DBNAME, false);

if (!function_exists('json_encode')) {
    function json_encode($content) {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../JSON.php';
        $json = new Services_JSON;
        return $json->encode($content);
    }
}

$myqevents       = array();
$last_stop       = array();
$last_stop_pause = array();
$agent_stats     = array();
$queue_stats     = array();
$outbound        = array();

$abr['COMPLETECALLER']   = 'CC';
$abr['COMPLETEAGENT']    = 'CA';
$abr['COMPLETEOUTBOUND'] = 'CO';
$abr['RINGNOANSWER']     = 'RA';
$abr['COMPLETED']        = 'COMPLETED';
$abr['COMPLETEDSLA']     = 'COMPLETEDSLA';
$abr['SERVICELEVEL']     = 'SERVICELEVEL';
$abr['ABANDONED']        = 'ABANDONED';
$abr['TALKTIME']         = 'TALKTIME';
$abr['WAITTIME']         = 'WAITTIME';

function parse_conf($filename) {

    $file = file($filename);

    foreach ($file AS $line) {
        if (preg_match("/^\s*([\w]+)\s*=\s*\"?([\w\/\:\.\*\%!=\+\#@&\\$-]*)\"?\s*([;].*)?/",$line,$matches)) {
            $conf[ $matches[1] ] = $matches[2];
        }
    }

    if(!isset($conf['manager_port'])) { $conf['manager_port']='0000';      }
    if(!isset($conf['manager_host'])) { $conf['manager_host']='0.0.0.0'; }

    return $conf;
}

if(is_file("/usr/local/fop2/fop2.cfg") || is_file("/etc/asterisk/fop2/fop2.cfg")) {
    if(is_file("/usr/local/fop2/fop2.cfg")) {
        $fop2conf = parse_conf("/usr/local/fop2/fop2.cfg");
    }
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM qevent ORDER BY null";
$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $myqevents[$row['event']] = $row['event_id'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM setup WHERE keyword='call_flow' OR keyword='sla_answered'";
$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if($row['value']=='outbound') {
        $outbound[]="\"".$row['parameter']."\"";
    }
    if($row['keyword']=='sla_answered') {
        $SLA_ANSWERED[$row['parameter']]=intval($row['value']);
    }
}

if(count($outbound)>0) {
    $outboundqueues = "AND queue NOT IN (".implode(",",$outbound).") ";
    $outboundquery  = "AND queue IN (".implode(",",$outbound).") ";
} else {
    $outboundqueues = '';
    $outboundquery  = '';
}

if($DEBUG & 1) {
    fputs($fp,"----- Session Times Start ----- \n\n");
}

$query = "SELECT @start:=NULL, @stop:=NULL, @qagent:=NULL";
$res = $db->consulta($query);  

$query = "SELECT queue_stats_id, agent, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(start) AS start, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(stop) AS stop, ";
$query.= "TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start, stop) AS duration ";
$query.= "FROM ( SELECT queue_stats_id, datetime, qevent, (@qagent <> qagent) AS new_qagent, ";
$query.= "@start AS start, @start := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['ADDMEMBER']."', datetime, NULL) AS prev_start, ";
$query.= "@stop  := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['REMOVEMEMBER']."', datetime, NULL) AS stop, @qagent := qagent AS qagent ";
$query.= "FROM queue_stats WHERE qevent IN (".$myqevents['ADDMEMBER'].",".$myqevents['REMOVEMEMBER'].") ORDER BY qagent, datetime ) AS tmp ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent = qagent.agent_id, (SELECT @start:=NULL, @stop:=NULL, @qagent:=NULL) AS vars ";
$query.= "WHERE new_qagent = 0 AND start IS NOT NULL AND stop IS NOT NULL and start>=CURDATE() $condagent";

$query = "SELECT queue_stats_id, agent, start, stop, (stop - start) AS duration ";
$query.= "FROM ( SELECT queue_stats_id,datetime,unix_timestamp(datetime),(@qagent <> qagent) AS new_qagent, ";
$query.= "agent,event, @prev_start := @start as start, ";
$query.= "@start := if(qevent='".$myqevents['ADDMEMBER']."',if(@start=0,unix_timestamp(datetime),if(@qagent<>qagent,unix_timestamp(datetime),@start)),0) as pstart, ";
$query.= "@stop  := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['REMOVEMEMBER']."', unix_timestamp(datetime), NULL) AS stop, ";
$query.= "@qagent := qagent FROM queue_stats LEFT JOIN qevent ON qevent=event_id ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent=agent_id, ( select @start := 0, @prev_start :=0, @qagent :='' ) sqlvars ";
$query.= "WHERE datetime>=CURDATE() AND qevent in (".$myqevents['ADDMEMBER'].",".$myqevents['REMOVEMEMBER'].") ORDER BY qagent,datetime) AS tmp ";
$query.= "WHERE start > 0 AND stop > 0 AND stop > start $condagent";

$res = $db->consulta($query);

if($DEBUG & 2) { 
    fputs($fp,"\nClosed sessions MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}

while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $last_stop[$row['agent']]=$row['stop']; // Save last stop date to use in open session query below
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT']=0; }
    $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST']+=$row['duration'];
    if($DEBUG & 4) {
        fputs($fp,"Agent closed session: ".$row['agent'].", sesion += ".$row['duration']." = ".$agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST']."\n");
    }
}

// Perform actual query for open sessions, (session with no closing event)
$query = "SELECT queue_stats_id,agent,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime) AS start,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now()) AS stop, ";
$query.= "TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,datetime,now()) AS duration FROM queue_stats ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent = qagent.agent_id WHERE qevent=".$myqevents['ADDMEMBER']." AND datetime>=CURDATE() $condagent";

$res = $db->consulta($query);
if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nOpen sessions MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if(!isset($last_stop[$row['agent']])) { $last_stop[$row['agent']]=$row['start']; } // We did not have a last stop from closed session so use the first start instead
    if($row['start']>=$last_stop[$row['agent']]) {
        if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]=array();}
        if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST']=0;}
        if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT']=0; }
        if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT']=0; }
        if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT']=0; }
        if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT']=0; }
        $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST']+=$row['duration'];
        $last_stop[$row['agent']]=time();  // If there is a match, last stop is current time
        if($DEBUG & 4) {
            fputs($fp,"Agent open session: ".$row['agent']." sesion += ".$row['duration']." = ".$agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST']."\n");
        }
    }
}

// Now, for agents with no start or stop sessions, lets just compute a session time from todays 00 hours
$query = "SELECT agent,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(now())-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) as ST FROM qagent WHERE 1=1";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nComputed sessions MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}
$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if(!in_array($row['agent'],$loggedInAgents)) {
        if($DEBUG & 4) { 
            fputs($fp,"Agent ".$row['agent']." is not logged, we can safely skip it.\n");
        }
    } else {
        if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST'])) {
            if($DEBUG & 1) {
                fputs($fp,"Agent computed session: ".$row['agent']." ST to ".$row['ST']."\n");
            }
            $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['ST']=$row['ST'];
            if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT']=0; }
            if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT']=0; }
            if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT']=0; }
            if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT']=0; }
        }
    }
}

if($DEBUG & 1) {
    fputs($fp,"----- Session Times End ----- \n\n");
}

// Call and Pause Stats for AGENTS
if($DEBUG & 1) {
    fputs($fp,"----- Agents Call Stats Start ----- \n");
}

// Total Pause duration for today, excluding pauses with reasons Hold, Login and Wrapup. Only counts "closed" pauses
$query = "SELECT @start:=NULL, @stop:=NULL, @qagent:=NULL";
$res = $db->consulta($query);  

// Perform actual query
$query = "SELECT queue_stats_id, agent, unix_timestamp(start) AS start, unix_timestamp(stop) AS stop, ";
$query.= "TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start, stop) AS duration FROM ( SELECT queue_stats_id, datetime, qevent, ";
$query.= "(@qagent <> qagent) AS new_qagent, @start AS start, ";
$query.= "@start := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['PAUSE']."' or qevent='".$myqevents['PAUSEALL']."', datetime, NULL) AS prev_start, ";
$query.= "@stop := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['UNPAUSE']."' or qevent='".$myqevents['UNPAUSEALL']."', datetime, NULL) AS stop, ";
$query.= "@qagent := qagent AS qagent FROM queue_stats WHERE qevent IN (".$myqevents['PAUSE'].",".$myqevents['PAUSEALL'].",".$myqevents['UNPAUSE'].",".$myqevents['UNPAUSEALL'].") ";
$query.= "AND info1<>'Hold' AND info1<>'Login' AND info1<>'Wrapup' AND datetime>=CURDATE() ORDER BY qagent, datetime ) AS tmp ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent = qagent.agent_id, (SELECT @start:=NULL, @stop:=NULL, @qagent:=NULL) AS vars ";
$query.= "WHERE new_qagent = 0 AND start IS NOT NULL AND stop IS NOT NULL $condagent";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nPauses (excluding hold and wrapup) MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}
$res = $db->consulta($query); 

while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $last_stop_pause[$row['agent']]=$row['stop'];
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT']=0; }
    $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT']+=$row['duration'];
    if($DEBUG & 4) {
        fputs($fp,"Regular Pause agent ".$row['agent']." += ".$row['duration'].", sums up to ".$agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT']."\n");
    }
}

// Total Pause duration with reason Hold, when using the Hold report plugin
$query = "SELECT @start:=NULL, @stop:=NULL, @qagent:=NULL, @reason:=NULL";
$res = $db->consulta($query);  

// Perform actual query
$query = "SELECT queue_stats_id, agent, unix_timestamp(start) AS start, unix_timestamp(stop) AS stop, ";
$query.= "TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start, stop) AS duration, reason from (SELECT queue_stats_id, datetime, qevent, ";
$query.= "(@qagent <> qagent) AS new_qagent, @start AS start, ";
$query.= "@start := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['PAUSE']."' or qevent='".$myqevents['PAUSEALL']."', datetime, NULL) AS prev_start, ";
$query.= "@stop := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['UNPAUSE']."' or qevent='".$myqevents['UNPAUSEALL']."', datetime, NULL) AS stop, ";
$query.= "@qagent := qagent AS qagent, @reason AS reason, ";
$query.= "@reason := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['PAUSE']."' or qevent='".$myqevents['PAUSEALL']."', info1, NULL) as prev_reason  ";
$query.= "FROM queue_stats WHERE qevent IN (".$myqevents['PAUSE'].",".$myqevents['PAUSEALL'].",".$myqevents['UNPAUSE'].",".$myqevents['UNPAUSEALL'].") ";
$query.= "AND datetime>=CURDATE() ORDER BY qagent, datetime) tmp LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent = qagent.agent_id, ";
$query.= "(SELECT @start:=NULL, @stop:=NULL, @qagent:=NULL,@reason:=NULL) AS vars ";
$query.= "WHERE start IS NOT NULL AND stop IS NOT NULL AND new_qagent=0 AND start>=CURDATE() AND reason='Hold' $condagent";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nPauses (Hold) MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}
$res = $db->consulta($query); 

while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $last_stop_pause[$row['agent']]=$row['stop'];
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT']=0; }
    $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT']+=$row['duration'];
    if($DEBUG & 4) {
        fputs($fp,"Hold Pause agent ".$row['agent']." += ".$row['duration'].", sums up to ".$agent_stats[$row['agent']]['HT']."\n");
    }
}

// Total Pause duration with reason Wrapup, when using the auto wrapup plugin with reason Wrapup 
$query = "SELECT @start:=NULL, @stop:=NULL, @qagent:=NULL, @reason:=NULL";
$res = $db->consulta($query);  

// Perform actual query
$query = "SELECT queue_stats_id, agent, unix_timestamp(start) AS start, unix_timestamp(stop) AS stop, ";
$query.= "TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start, stop) AS duration, reason from (SELECT queue_stats_id, datetime, qevent, ";
$query.= "(@qagent <> qagent) AS new_qagent, @start AS start, ";
$query.= "@start := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['PAUSE']."' or qevent='".$myqevents['PAUSEALL']."', datetime, NULL) AS prev_start, ";
$query.= "@stop := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['UNPAUSE']."' or qevent='".$myqevents['UNPAUSEALL']."', datetime, NULL) AS stop, ";
$query.= "@qagent := qagent AS qagent, @reason AS reason, ";
$query.= "@reason := IF(qevent = '".$myqevents['PAUSE']."' or qevent='".$myqevents['PAUSEALL']."', info1, NULL) as prev_reason  ";
$query.= "FROM queue_stats WHERE qevent IN (".$myqevents['PAUSE'].",".$myqevents['PAUSEALL'].",".$myqevents['UNPAUSE'].",".$myqevents['UNPAUSEALL'].") ";
$query.= "AND datetime>=CURDATE() ORDER BY qagent, datetime) tmp LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent = qagent.agent_id, ";
$query.= "(SELECT @start:=NULL, @stop:=NULL, @qagent:=NULL,@reason:=NULL) AS vars ";
$query.= "WHERE start IS NOT NULL AND stop IS NOT NULL AND new_qagent=0 AND reason='Wrapup' $condagent";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nPauses (Wrapup) MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}
$res = $db->consulta($query); 

while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $last_stop_pause[$row['agent']]=$row['stop'];
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT']=0; }
    $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT']+=$row['duration'];
    if($DEBUG & 4) {
        fputs($fp,"Wrapup Pause agent ".$row['agent']." += ".$row['duration'].", sums up to ".$agent_stats[$row['agent']]['WT']."\n");
    }
}

// check for Open Pauses now, open pauses with no unpause, discarding hold and wrapup
$query = "SELECT queue_stats_id,agent,unix_timestamp(datetime) AS start, ";
$query.= "unix_timestamp(now()) AS stop, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,datetime,now()) AS duration ";
$query.= "FROM queue_stats LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent = qagent.agent_id ";
$query.= "WHERE qevent IN (".$myqevents['PAUSE'].",".$myqevents['PAUSEALL'].") AND datetime>=CURDATE() AND (info1<>'Hold' AND info1<>'Wrapup') $condagent";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nOpen Pauses MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}

$res = $db->consulta($query);

while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if(!isset($last_stop_pause[$row['agent']])) { $last_stop_pause[$row['agent']]=$row['start']; }
    if($row['start']>=$last_stop_pause[$row['agent']]) {
        if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT']=0; }
        $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT']+=$row['duration'];
        if($DEBUG & 4) {
            fputs($fp,"Open pause agent ".$row['agent']." += ".$row['duration'].", sums up to ".$agent_stats[$row['agent']]['PT']."\n");
        }
        $last_stop_pause[$row['agent']]=time();  
    }
}

// TALKTIME for today, per agent
$query = "SELECT agent,sum(info2) AS talktime ";
$query.= "FROM queue_stats LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent=qagent.agent_id ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qevent ON qevent=qevent.event_id ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qname ON qname=qname.queue_id ";
$query.= "WHERE qevent IN(".$myqevents['COMPLETECALLER'].",".$myqevents['COMPLETEAGENT'].") $outboundqueues ";
$query.= "AND datetime >= CURDATE() $condagent GROUP BY qagent";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nTalk time MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}

$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT']=$row['talktime'];
    if($DEBUG & 4) {
        fputs($fp,"Talk time agent ".$row['agent']." = ".$row['talktime']."\n");
    }
}

// RING NO ANSWER y COMPLETE  for today, per agent
$query = "SELECT agent,event,count(qevent) AS count FROM queue_stats ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent=qagent.agent_id ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qevent ON qevent=qevent.event_id ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qname ON qname=qname.queue_id ";
$query.=" WHERE qevent IN(".$myqevents['COMPLETECALLER'].",".$myqevents['COMPLETEAGENT'].",".$myqevents['RINGNOANSWER'].") $outboundqueues ";
$query.= "AND datetime >= CURDATE() $condagent GROUP BY qagent,qevent";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nRingNoAnswer and Complete* MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}

$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $agent_stats[$row['agent']][$abr[$row['event']]]=$row['count'];
    if($DEBUG & 4) {
        fputs($fp,"Completed agent ".$row['agent'].", event ".$row['event']." = ".$row['count']."\n");
    }
}

// OUTBOUND for today using Asternic call_flow setup. Requires a licensed Asternicy
if($outboundquery<>'') {

    $query = "SELECT agent,event,count(qevent) AS count FROM queue_stats ";
    $query.= "LEFT JOIN qagent ON qagent=qagent.agent_id LEFT JOIN qevent ON qevent=qevent.event_id ";
    $query.= "LEFT JOIN qname ON qname=qname.queue_id WHERE qevent ";
    $query.= "IN(".$myqevents['COMPLETECALLER'].",".$myqevents['COMPLETEAGENT'].") $outboundquery AND datetime >= CURDATE() $condagent ";
    $query.= "GROUP BY qagent,qevent";

    if($DEBUG & 2) {
        fputs($fp,"\nOutbound query via  Asternic call_flow queues MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
    }

    $res = $db->consulta($query);
    while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $agent_stats[$row['agent']][$abr['COMPLETEOUTBOUND']]=$row['count'];
        if($DEBUG & 4) {
            fputs($fp,"Outbound asternic agent ".$row['agent']." = ".$row['count']."\n");
        }
    }

}

// Use CDR table for outbound count in a FreePBX System. For this to work 
// we must be sure the Asternic user is able to access asteriskcdrdb.cdr 
// table

/* Custom query */
$query = "SELECT agent,count(*) as count,data2 as talktime ";
$query.= "FROM queuemetrics.queue_log ";
$query.= "WHERE partition = 'P001' ";
$query.= "AND time_id >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURDATE()) ";
$query.= "AND verb IN ('COMPLETECALLER', 'COMPLETEAGENT') AND data3 = '' $condagent ";
$query.= "GROUP BY agent ";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nOutbound query via FreePBX CDR MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}

$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $agent_stats[$row['agent']][$abr['COMPLETEOUTBOUND']]=$row['count'];
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT'])) { $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT']=0; }
    $agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT']+=$row['talktime'];
    if($DEBUG & 4) {
        fputs($fp,"Outbound cdr agent ".$row['agent']." = ".$row['count']."\n");
        fputs($fp,"Outbound cdr agent talktime ".$row['agent']." = ".$agent_stats[$row['agent']]['TT']."\n");
    }
}

foreach($agent_stats AS $agent=>$nada) {
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$agent]['PT'])) { $agent_stats[$agent]['PT']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$agent]['ST'])) { $agent_stats[$agent]['ST']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$agent]['CC'])) { $agent_stats[$agent]['CC']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$agent]['CA'])) { $agent_stats[$agent]['CA']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$agent]['CO'])) { $agent_stats[$agent]['CO']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$agent]['RA'])) { $agent_stats[$agent]['RA']=0; }
    if(!isset($agent_stats[$agent]['TT'])) { $agent_stats[$agent]['TT']=0; }

    if(preg_match("/Agent\//",$agent)) {
        $numeric_agent = preg_replace("/Agent\//","",$agent);
        $agent_stats[$numeric_agent]=$agent_stats[$agent];
    }

}

if($DEBUG & 1) {
    fputs($fp,print_r($agent_stats,1));
    fputs($fp,"----- Agents Call Stats End ----- \n\n");
}

if($DEBUG & 1) {
    fputs($fp,"----- Queue Stats Start ----- \n");
}

// Queue Stats Queries

$query = "SELECT queue FROM qname WHERE queue NOT IN ('All','None')";
if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nQueues filler MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}

$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['SERVICELEVEL']])) { 
        $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['SERVICELEVEL']]=isset($SLA_ANSWERED[$row['queue']])?$SLA_ANSWERED[$row['queue']]:$SLA_ANSWERED[''];
    }
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['COMPLETEDSLA']])) { $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['COMPLETEDSLA']]=0; }
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['COMPLETED']])) { $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['COMPLETED']]=0; }
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['TALKTIME']])) { $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['TALKTIME']]=0; }
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['WAITTIME']])) { $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['WAITTIME']]=0; }
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['ABANDONED']])) { $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['ABANDONED']]=0; }
}

// total completed caller and agent
$query = "SELECT count(*) AS count,queue,sum(info1) as waittime, sum(info2) as talktime ";
$query.= "FROM queue_stats LEFT JOIN qevent ON qevent=qevent.event_id ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qname ON qname=qname.queue_id ";
$query.= "WHERE datetime>=CURDATE() AND event IN ('COMPLETECALLER','COMPLETEAGENT','TRANSFER') GROUP BY qname ORDER BY null";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nQueues Completed MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}

$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['COMPLETED']]=intval($row['count']);
    $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['COMPLETEDSLA']]=0;
    $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['TALKTIME']]=intval($row['talktime']);
    $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['WAITTIME']]=intval($row['waittime']);

    if($DEBUG & 4) {
        fputs($fp,"Queue ".$row['queue'].", completed: ".$row['count'].", TalkTime: ".$row['talktime'].", Wait Time: ".$row['waittime']."\n");
    }
}

// completed under sla 
$query = "SELECT queue,info1  ";
$query.= "FROM queue_stats LEFT JOIN qevent ON qevent=qevent.event_id ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qname ON qname=qname.queue_id ";
$query.= "WHERE datetime>=CURDATE() AND event IN ('COMPLETECALLER','COMPLETEAGENT','TRANSFER') $outboundqueues ORDER BY null";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nQueues Completed SLA MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}

$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $sla = (isset($SLA_ANSWERED[$row['queue']]))?$SLA_ANSWERED[$row['queue']]:$SLA_ANSWERED[''];
    $waittime = $row['info1'];
    if($waittime<=$sla) {
        $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['COMPLETEDSLA']]++;
    }
}

// exit and abandon
$query = "SELECT count(*) AS count,queue,sum(info3) as waittime FROM queue_stats ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qevent ON qevent=qevent.event_id ";
$query.= "LEFT JOIN qname ON qname=qname.queue_id ";
$query.= "WHERE datetime>=CURDATE() AND event IN ('ABANDON','EXITWITHKEY','EXITWITHTIMEOUT','EXITEMPTY') GROUP BY qname ORDER BY null";

if($DEBUG & 2) {
    fputs($fp,"\nQueues no answer/abandon MySQL query:\n\n$query\n\n");
}
$res = $db->consulta($query);
while($row=$db->fetch_assoc($res)) {
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['COMPLETED']])) { $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['COMPLETED']]=0; }
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['TALKTIME']])) { $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['TALKTIME']]=0; }
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['WAITTIME']])) { $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['WAITTIME']]=0; }
    if(!isset($queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['ABANDONED']])) { $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['ABANDONED']]=0; }
    $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['ABANDONED']]=intval($row['count']);
    $queue_stats[$row['queue']][$abr['WAITTIME']]+=intval($row['waittime']);
    if($DEBUG & 4) {
        fputs($fp,"Queue ".$row['queue'].", abandoned: ".$row['count'].", Wait Time: ".$row['waittime']."\n");
    }
}

if($DEBUG & 1) {
    fputs($fp,print_r($queue_stats,1));
    fputs($fp,"----- Queue Stats End ----- \n\n");
}

// Connect to AMI and fire events for every piece of stats we have
if(!$res = $astman->connect($fop2conf['manager_host'].':'.$fop2conf['manager_port'], $fop2conf['manager_user'] , $fop2conf['manager_secret'], 'off')) {
    unset($astman);
}

if ($astman) {

    foreach ($agent_stats as $key => $nada) {
        // we have to send individual events as there is a limit in AMI events header size
        $pepe_stats = Array();
        $pepe_stats[$key] = $agent_stats[$key];
        $json_data = json_encode($pepe_stats);
        $res = $astman->UserEvent('ASTERNICAGENTSTATS',array('Channel'=>'GLOBAL_FULLWALLBOARD','Family'=>'ASTERNICAGENTSTATS','Value'=>base64_encode($json_data)));
    }

    $res = $astman->UserEvent('ASTERNICQUEUESTATSRESET',array('Channel'=>'GLOBAL_FULLWALLBOARD','Family'=>'ASTERNICQUEUESTATSRESET','Value'=>''));
    foreach ($queue_stats as $key => $nada) {
        $pepe_stats = Array();
        $pepe_stats[$key] = $queue_stats[$key];
        $json_data = json_encode($pepe_stats);
        $res = $astman->UserEvent('ASTERNICQUEUESTATS',array('Channel'=>'GLOBAL_FULLWALLBOARD','Family'=>'ASTERNICQUEUESTATS','Value'=>base64_encode($json_data)));
    }
    $res = $astman->UserEvent('ASTERNICQUEUESTATSEND',array('Channel'=>'GLOBAL_FULLWALLBOARD','Family'=>'ASTERNICQUEUESTATSEND','Value'=>''));
}

if($DEBUG & 1) {
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Please note that I have without key Asternic installed without license as it is not mandatory to run plugin.

Comment: What you want require at least 4-5hrs for expert to investigate. It is not something standart nor something can be answered in less then one page of text.

Comment: I agree with you. But I taught there might be some expert here how have well known FOP2 and can contribute his advice / suggestion. I can provide you more info if you can help me in this regards.